# get the newest order for each group

Tags: oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to get the newest order for each phone number so I used in oracle

```
select * from (select * from orders where phonenum ='914780' order by order_date)
where rownum<=1
```

it works for one number only if I used it of several number it give me wrong results
as each number has several orders

Answer (score 1):

Use window function for ordering phone number wise orders and then pick each phone number latest record.

```sql
Select * 
from (
  Select o.*,
         row_number() over (partition by phonenum order by order_id desc) AS rowno 
  from order o
  Where phonenum = '1233'
) t
Where t.rowno = 1;
```

N.B.: use table name and columns according to your DB objects.